# "Hot swapping" code with swank clojure, and crash resilience

Tags: clojure, swank, swank-clojure

I've been messing around with developing a game in clojure, and one thing I've been really excited about is hot swapping in code.

I've been using swank clojure and emacs with the `lein-swank` plugin.

My main problem has been that of typos. Say I update a function, make a small error, and then hit Ctrl-C Ctrl-C to send it off to the REPL:

`(if (> (rand) .5) (println "yay") (println "boo"))`

(I should have written `0.5`, not `.5`.)

In that case, the entire program will simply crash and burn, and I'll need to restart the whole thing. Hot swapping is great, but if I can't make even a tiny error then what's the point?

So what exactly is the workflow here? Am I missing something? Or is there a way to make swank clojure more resilient to these little errors? (I imagine that the best thing would simply be to reset to a previous working state, although that may be a little difficult.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program shouldn't “crash and burn”—it should raise an exception and throw you into the debugger, which you can dismiss by hitting `Q` (`sldb-quit`).  After dismissing the debugger, the program is supposed to continue running normally.  If this is not what happens, your SLIME configuration is probably broken somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I recommend C-M-x over C-c C-c. I don't think either one should have the problem you're experiencing, though, so switching may not fix it.

Comment: Really? What happens when you accidentally C-M-x some code that accesses a property of nil or something? Would that imply that my setup is messed up somehow?

Comment: \*shrug\* Slime opens up a window with a stacktrace. I look through it if there's anything interesting, and then press Q to dismiss it and get back to work.